# React form returns 404 not found when trying to sign up with Devise Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, devise

I'm trying to make a simple form that allows users to sign up for a new account using React JS and Ruby on Rails API. I am using the devise/devise authentication API gem for my account. I made a form with react, but when I submit my form it returns a 404 not found error.[image]

Interesting thing is that when I use postman to run the exact same request, it registers a new user successfully.

[image]

I've tried connecting it to other routes, changing the request type but nothing seems to work. I'm running my React app on port 8080 and rails 3000.

Here is my current code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class Registration extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      password_confirmation: "",
      registrationErrors: ""
    };

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted");
    const { email, password, password_confirmation } = this.state;
    axios
      .post(
        "/auth",
        {
          user: {
            email,
            password,
            password_confirmation
          }
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      )
      .then(response => {
        console.log("registration res", response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("egistration", error);
      });

    // axios returns a promise so need to use a then to convert it to json
    // then give out errors if there are any
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type='email'
            name='email'
            placeholder='Email'
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            required
          />

          <input
            type='password'
            name='password'
            placeholder='Password'
            value={this.state.password}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            required
          />

          <input
            type='password'
            name='password_confirmation'
            placeholder='Password Confirmation'
            value={this.state.password_confirmation}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            required
          />

          <button type='submit'>Register</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Registration;
```

app/controllers/auth/registrations_controller.rb

```
module Auth
  class RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController
    def new
      user = User.new
    end

    def create
      user = User.new(sign_up_params)
      if user.save
        render json: {status: "SUCCESS", message: "added a new user!", data: user}, status: :ok
      else
        render json: {status: "ERROR", message: "couldn't add a user", data: user.errors}, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    private
    def sign_up_params
      params.permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
    def account_update_params
      params.permit(:name, :email)
    end
  end
 end
```

Rails routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
    registrations: 'auth/registrations'
   }
end

         new_user_session GET    /auth/sign_in(.:format)                                                                  devise_token_auth/sessions#new
             user_session POST   /auth/sign_in(.:format)                                                                  devise_token_auth/sessions#create
     destroy_user_session DELETE /auth/sign_out(.:format)                                                                 devise_token_auth/sessions#destroy
        new_user_password GET    /auth/password/new(.:format)                                                             devise_token_auth/passwords#new
       edit_user_password GET    /auth/password/edit(.:format)                                                            devise_token_auth/passwords#edit
            user_password PATCH  /auth/password(.:format)                                                                 devise_token_auth/passwords#update
                          PUT    /auth/password(.:format)                                                                 devise_token_auth/passwords#update
                          POST   /auth/password(.:format)                                                                 devise_token_auth/passwords#create
 cancel_user_registration GET    /auth/cancel(.:format)                                                                   auth/registrations#cancel
    new_user_registration GET    /auth/sign_up(.:format)                                                                  auth/registrations#new
   edit_user_registration GET    /auth/edit(.:format)                                                                     auth/registrations#edit
        user_registration PATCH  /auth(.:format)                                                                          auth/registrations#update
                          PUT    /auth(.:format)                                                                          auth/registrations#update
                          DELETE /auth(.:format)                                                                          auth/registrations#destroy
                          POST   /auth(.:format)                                                                          auth/registrations#create
      auth_validate_token GET    /auth/validate_token(.:format)                                                           devise_token_auth/token_validations#validate_token
       rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

I would appreciate any insights.

UPDATE: I tried changing the port number of my react app to 3000 and my rails API to 3001 since the url was inputted in postman was a localhost 3000. But still the same error is returned.

UPDATE2: Below are the network tabs.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE: Attached is the postman headers and payload[image]
[image]

Comment: Am I wrong or you send request from react to `localhost:8080` instead of `localhost:3000`?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev I was sending it to 8080. But as stated in the question, I did change the port number of the react app to ```localhost:3000```  and the rails port to ```localhost:3001``` . Still no luck even though I changed it to 3000.

Comment: What if you change url path from `/auth` to `http://localhost:3000/auth` ? Did you try?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev Yes I did, and it still throws the same 404 error.

Comment: Can you attach Network tab with request on it?

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev, I have edited the question and attached the network tab

Comment: Can you add the payload and headers you are sending through postman?
I suspect that perhaps you're sending something there that is not present on the axios request, like a Content-Type: application/json header.

Comment: @cesartalves I have attached the payload (I assume you're talking about the raw json) and the headers. 
I haven't attached a content type option inside the axios request, and I actually tried putting it in but unfortunately it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the axios body. You're sending the fields inside an user json key, and not specifying the keys for the other fields. Try removing that key and just sending the e-mail, password and password confirmation.

Like this:

```
axios.post("/auth", {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            password_confirmation: password_confirmation
          },
        { withCredentials: true }
      )
```

If that doesn't work, it might have something to do with the withCredentials option.

In any case, take a look into axios' docs to see it's options https://github.com/axios/axios

You could use the Network tab to analyse the request sent and see how the params and headers differ from the ones on postman.